# Port forwarding to asp.net development server

Tags: port-forwarding, asp.net, development

I have configured my router so that I can access my local host from internet.

But I can't manage to port forward it to asp.net development server.

In the router's port forwarding I did the same thing as for the local host but only changed the port number so that it is the same as the one that is assigned to my application, but this doesn't work. Any idea how to get it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The ASP.NET Development Server will not serve pages to remote computers](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/tips/remap_function_keys.html):

> In other words, the ASP.NET Development Server will serve pages to browser requests on the local computer. It will not serve pages to another computer.

To make your ASP.NET website available to another computer, you'll need to install and use IIS.

The instructions are different depending on which version of Windows you're using, but the first step is to make sure it's actually installed.  On Windows XP, [it's found in Add/Remove Programs](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp_tutorials/installing_iis_winxp_pro.asp).  On Visa or Windows 7, [IIS can be installed from the Programs and Features applet](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use IIS and want to stick to the asp.net development server.

try freeware SPI port forward, http://download.cnet.com/SPI-Port-Forward/3000-2651_4-10764348.html

It's a tiny portable program, I used it with visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2010 in some commerical projects successfully.